# How to build a neural network with one single hidden layer using keras?

Tags: r, keras

I want to train a simple 1-hidden layer network.
The network shhould consist of three layers: One input layer (2 dims), one hidden layer (10 dims) and one output layer (1 dim).
The activation functions for the input layer should be linear, for the hidden layer sigmoid, and for the output layer also linear (because I am doing a regression task).

The following is my code:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 10, activation = 'sigmoid', input_shape = 2)
```

This results in an error:

```
 Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
   ValueError: A target array with shape (625, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 10) while using as loss `mean_squared_error`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
```

The problem seems to be that my target label is one dimensional but the output of the network above 10-dimensional.

Thus, I change the model the following:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  layer_dense(units = 10, activation = 'sigmoid', input_shape = ncol(x_train)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'linear')
```

Now I can compile the network.

Plotting the weights results in the following:

```
> get_weights(model)
[[1]]
         [,1]       [,2]       [,3]     [,4]       [,5]      [,6]       [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     [,10]
[1,] 1.250297 -2.6194241 -1.5429267 1.025575 -1.9918470 2.1469700 -1.4964410 0.7511418 0.9715033 0.9903362
[2,] 2.805784 -0.2100081 -0.8766818 2.319680  0.6840908 0.3205897 -0.8494857 3.8642540 1.8826129 2.0817966

[[2]]
  [1] -0.020989 -2.063512 -4.764145 -4.091934  1.964735 -5.380935 -4.615426  4.845552 -2.825072 -3.375803

[[3]]
           [,1]
 [1,]  3.338166
 [2,] -2.492730
 [3,] -3.012555
 [4,]  2.306220
 [5,] -2.523774
 [6,]  3.265386
 [7,] -2.959120
 [8,]  4.011787
 [9,]  1.740327
 [10,]  2.033795

[[4]]
[1] -0.2520685
```

This output is confusing.
[[1]] seems to be, as desired, the connection to the hidden layer with 10 neurons. Layer [[2]] seems to be the connections from the hidden layer to the output layer which summarizes the output of the hidden neurons.
However, I don't understand what [[3]] and [[4]] is here? [[4]] Seems to represent the final output connection weight, but what is [[3]]?

How can I build a network with 10 hidden neurons and a single linear output neuron?

Comment: I edited again to properly address last question. If it answers the question you can accept it:).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second and fourth output represent the biases of your dense layer. Basically dense layer has first a matrix of correct shape with which you multiply the input layer, then you add the bias before the activation function. You can imagine them as moving the activation function left or right, for example tanh.

```
input %*% matrix_weights + bias

# in your case

input %*% weights[[1]] + weights[[2]]
```

EDIT: Did not see last question:

If you do not want biases keras har a parameter that allows to disable them. Simply use `use_bias=F` when configuring dense layer.

Without biases your are building simple perceptron, so personally I see no harm if you allow them. If they really cannot add any information, the network itself would put them close to 0. If that is the case you can hand correct them later or retrain the net without biases.

The [[3]] part actually represents the weights from first layer to second. So first layer with shape (,10) and then you need to reduce it (,1) while each of the 10 features contributes something to the last one. The [[3]] tells you the weight of the contributions.